# Can't expand "Alfred 3 Snippets" at integrated terminal within Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, alfred

I wonder if you please can give me a hand here...

I've setup couple of snippets at Alfred 3 and it works everywhere except inside the integrated terminal at Visual Studio Code.

When I type the keyword, you would expect to paste whatever you have defined in Alfred, but instead, it will copy what you have at the clipboard.

Do you know by any chance how could I have this to paste the right value from Alfred and not what I have at the clipboard?

For Example:

- Alfred 3 Snippet - keyword: dd, text to expand: "dd();"

When I type dd at the integrated terminal at Visual Studio Code, it expands whatever I have in the clipboard and NOT dd();

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found what the issue was... in case some one has the same.

Turn out, I needed to decrease the speed of the autocompletion option in Alfred.
After setting 1 millisec delay, it worked.